# Get members of Active Directory Group

Tags: c#

I have this Code.
it works i'm getting the members of the group
But i'm getting lots of Exception thrown?
I'm getting all the correct names in my textbox
So i don't know why i'm getting the error?

Anyone here know why?

> Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in mscorlib.dll Exception
>   thrown: 'System.FormatException' in mscorlib.dll Exception thrown:
>   'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' in
>   System.DirectoryServices.dll Exception thrown:
>   'System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryServicesCOMException' in
>   System.DirectoryServices.dll

```
string pathNameDomain = "domain";
string domainAndUsername = @"domain\username";
string pwd = "password";

PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, pathNameDomain, domainAndUsername, pwd);

GroupPrincipal group = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, groupname);

if (group != null)
{
    foreach (Principal p in group.GetMembers())
    {
        //Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", p.StructuralObjectClass, p.DisplayName);

         UserPrincipal theUser = p as UserPrincipal;

         if (theUser != null)
         {
            resultattxt.Text += p.DisplayName;
            resultattxt.Text += Environment.NewLine;
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the exception?

Comment: Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.FormatException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' in System.DirectoryServices.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryServicesCOMException' in System.DirectoryServices.dll

Comment: Is it because there is other groups in the group?

Comment: Where is the exception thrown? Did you try to debug line-by-line?

Comment: I would edit this code put all of it inside a `try - catch` block.  Debug the code and catch the exception to get more details out of it.

Comment: I'm using try and catch... but catch is not catching it!...
the error comes after this: PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, pathNameDomain, domainAndUsername, pwd);

Comment: Old post but The question is still relevant. when I run the following line, the result is OK but the execution is slow and I can see two exceptions ( first chance ? ) in the output windows in Visual Studio 2019:

GroupPrincipal group = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, groupname);

Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in mscorlib.dll

Exception thrown: 'System.FormatException' in mscorlib.dll

Does anyone knows why ?